Toggle Toolbar in Jupyter Notebook
I would like to toggle the toolbar in Jupyter Notebook (version 7.2.2). I know this function was present back in the day but now in the View menu there is only "Toggle Zen Mode".
Is there a way to toggle the toolbar? I don't really use it that often as I rely primarily on shortcuts and it would be great if I could free up some screen real estate.
Thank you in advance.


Thanks for the observation. I uploaded a newer screenshot.

My understanding is that there isn't such a feature yet in JupyterLab, see this discussion in the presently still open 'How to toggle the toolbar?'. And since Jupyter Notebook 7+ is built on JupyterLab components, that is important. There is a related discussion for Jupyter Notebook 7+ that says as much here for Jupyter Notebook not yet having having that feature, see the discussion related to the presently still-open issue 'V7: Can't hide toolbar.'.
You should be able to hide the toolbar though by adjusting settings using the 'Settings Editor'.
See more about that in Jupyter Notebook's 'Interface Customization' page, which will lead you to JupyterLab's Interface Customization' as it is is built on JupyterLab components and so much of the same methods of doing things hold now.
By the way, in Jupyter Notebook 7+, at this time the easiest way to find the 'Settings Editor' when in the Notebook interface is to go to the File menu and select 'View' > 'File Browser'. Then on the 'Fle Browser' page you'll see 'Settings' asa choice along the File menu. The 'Settings' menu context here is expanded and includes a choice of 'Settings Editor''.

If you prefer, you can still use NbClassic, see more about that here and here.
